# Disable updated scroll RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

On the Home page, user posts are displayed , When you click on the image, the image is converted to a slightly transparent image and the title is displayed inside it, but at the 7th image on the home page, the seventh image is replaced with the same first image when clicked

The first seven pictures are clicked on when the seventh picture changes and the first picture becomes the picture on the picture number seven

I uploaded a video that shows the mistake that is happening

[video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zgDYa3BZdY)

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        private RecyclerView mPandaList, StroyRecyc;
        private DatabaseReference MData_For_Home, mStory, FUI, FUI2, mDatabaseUsers, user_is_blocked;
        private Query MData_For_Limitet;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;
        private Query query;
        private static final int GALLERY_REQ = 1;
        private FirebaseUser mCurrentUsers;
        private ImageButton Story_image_add;
        private static final String TAG = "home";
        private Uri mImageUri = null;
        private boolean isTrue = false;
        private boolean isStored = false;
        private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
        private StorageReference storageReference;

        //private String p_sition = null;

        private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_helper);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting.");



            mPandaList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.panda_Posts);
            mPandaList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mPandaList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



            MData_For_Home = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
        }



        @Override
        protected void onStart() {

            mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
            super.onStart();

            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<panda, PandaViewHolder> FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<panda, PandaViewHolder>(
                    panda.class,
                    R.layout.home_post_adapter,
                    PandaViewHolder.class,
                    MData_For_Home

            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final PandaViewHolder viewHolder, final panda model, final int position) {

                    final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

                    viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                    viewHolder.setUid(model.getUid());
                    viewHolder.setImage(getApplication(), model.getImage());
                    viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
                    viewHolder.setPandaId(model.getPandaid());
                    viewHolder.isView = true;
                    viewHolder.isselect = false;
                    viewHolder.setUserprofile(getApplication(), model.getUserprofile());
                    viewHolder.tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/fonts3.ttf");
                    viewHolder.pandauserid.setTypeface(viewHolder.tf);


                }
            };
            mPandaList.setAdapter(FBRA);

        }


        public static class PandaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


            View mView;
            ImageView post_image;
            BlurImageView post_image1;
            boolean isView = false;
            boolean isselect = false;
            boolean IsLiked = false;
            TextView post_title;
            DatabaseReference mDatabase;
            DatabaseReference mUsersBase;
            FirebaseUser mCurrentUsers;
            FirebaseAuth mAuth;
            DatabaseReference mDatabaase;
            DatabaseReference Admin;
            ImageButton LikeButton;
            Typeface tf;
            TextView pandauserid;
            Button Comment;
            TextView Comments;
            TextView Like;

            public PandaViewHolder(View itemView) {


                super(itemView);
                mView = itemView;
                isView = false;
                isselect = false;
                post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.userpb);
                post_image1 = (BlurImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_imageview);
                post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
                post_title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                pandauserid = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.panda_users_pid);
                Comment = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.AddCommentValueListenr);
                Comments = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView77);
                LikeButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.button20);
                Like = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView76);
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users_Notify");
                mUsersBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                Admin = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Admin");
                mCurrentUsers = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                mDatabaase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
                IsLiked = false;



            }


            // post text view
            public void setTitle(final String title) {

                post_title.setText(title);


                //..... To Copy The TEXTS
                post_title.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) mView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", post_title.getText().toString());
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);


                        Vibrator aaa = (Vibrator) mView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        aaa.vibrate(150);

                        Toast.makeText(mView.getContext(), R.string.copy_to, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }




    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "The screen is passed back to the beginning"? Is it another activity or what is it? Does the activity you return to have the RecyclerView or is it both?

Comment: The main activity is a posts view page, when you click on a comment button it moves to another activity and when you return from the comments, RecycleView returns to 0

Comment: That may be due to recreating the activity. Do you return to the posts view with `startActivity()` or with `finish()` etc.?

Comment: The question has been updated, I never call the kids inside the start of the call onStart () and does this cause any difference?

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand what you mean by "calling the kids". Could you please state the control flow of your app, something like `Click on Comment` -> `Do something in other activity` -> `Calling finish()` -> `ListView State did not save` - But i don't know if that is really the control flow. Also, could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as I don't really want to read ~200 LoC.